# force module namespace qualification

Tags: vb.net, module, namespaces

VB.net allows you to skip the qualification of a function call with the module name:

```
Public Module EvalDataFetcher

    Public Function JoinStr(ByVal values As IEnumerable(Of String)) As String
        ' body
    End Function

End Module
```

And then do:

```
Dim foo As String = JoinStr(myBars)
```

How to force the users to use the fully qualified form? ie force:

```
Dim foo As String = EvalDataFetcher.JoinStr(myBars)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a way to force you to specify the module name, I'm not sure what it would be.  However, the way you ca do it is to make it a class with shared members rather than a module.  For instance:

```
Public Class EvalDataFetcher
    Public Shared Function JoinStr(ByVal values As IEnumerable(Of String)) As String
        ' body
    End Function
End Module
```

Now, when you call the `JoinStr` method, you will be forced to specify the class name:

```
Dim foo1 As String = JoinStr(myBars)  ' Won't compile
Dim foo2 As String = EvalDataFetcher.JoinStr(myBars)  ' Works
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that I will just move all my modules in namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

This behavior can be achieved with `HideModuleName` attribute as workaround - [HideModuleNameAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85a47y0y(v=vs.90).aspx)
Wrap your module with namespace and add `HideModuleName` attribute to the module

```vb
Namespace Utils

    <HideModuleName()>
    Friend Module UtilsModule

        Public Sub YourMethod(parameter As Object)
            'Method code
        End Sub

    End Module

End Namespace
```

If namespace will  not be added with the `Imports` in the file, then
you will need to use namespace name and `HideModuleName` attribute will hide module name from the intellisense

```
Utils.YourMethod(param)
```